# Should I add a common property of foreign keys to my table?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I have a database of test data that have been collected on behalf of agents. The test data are grouped together (after the fact) into result sets. As the tests come in, they are stored in the database with the ID of the corresponding agent:

```
TEST_ID TEST_OWNER TIMESTAMP RESULT_ID
      1          1         0      null
      2          1        15      null
      3          2        30      null
      4          2        32      null
      5          1        34      null
```

The result sets are generated at a later time in such a way that groups tests that took place during a similar time frame. This judgment cannot be made as the tests come in.

```
RESULT_ID
        1
        2
        3
```

All of the tests in a result set must belong to the same owner. I can ensure this (in code) as I assign the result IDs to the tests in my later operation, but some things would be easier if I had a `TEST_OWNER` field in my result set table.

Would adding this field be a violation of some normalization goal? The `TEST_OWNER` information will be duplicated, even though one instance of it is really implicit. I'm not a DBA, and I don't want to do things that are bad style.

Comment: Why do you mean by "but some things would be easier" ?
BTW, if your can store your `RESULT_ID`s directly in the `TEST` table as soon as they come, you shouldn't need to bother adding a `TEST_OWNER` field in your result set table.

Comment: With TEST_OWNER in the result table, I wouldn't need to scan for an entry in the test table that had a particular result ID to figure out which tests are candidates for having that result ID.

Comment: As I said, I can't make the judgment of which tests should be grouped together into a result set until all of the tests have come in. The grouping is done with a heuristic that looks backward and forward in time.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the meaning of `RESULT_ID`... When dealing with difficult "timing" cases such as this one, or performances, IMO it isn't a shame to store some redundant / computed data in DB, even if we don't fully comply with the normalization principles.

Answer (score 1):

Jim I am not completely sure if you are saying this is a table in your DB??

```
TEST_ID TEST_OWNER TIMESTAMP RESULT_ID
      1          1         0      null
      2          1        15      null
      3          2        30      null
      4          2        32      null
      5          1        34      null
```

If so the first thing I would do is pull the result attribute out of this table to achieve normalization.  Or is this your Result table?

Regardless are these results being derived from from other data in the DB?  If so I don't see the need to duplicate things and store the results (calculated) also. Just derive as needed and keep the DB clean.

If you need further info I need a better understanding of what you are presenting.

Comment: That is a table in the DB. After the batch process, the RESULT_ID fields get filled in. Are you saying I need a third table that shows what tests are in a result set? What would this table look like?

Comment: The RESULT_ID field in this table is a foreign key, if that helps you see what's going on.

Comment: @Jim Hunziker When is the Timestamp generated?  According to what you have it would be before the RESULT_ID gets populated right?  What we need to get rid of is the NULL.  If you can post a diagram of what you currently have that would be a huge help in getting you to where you want to be.